# Reason - Activity getting recreated.

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an Activity-A in my Android APP. The activity-A always getting recreated in a particular device but not on majority of other devices that I have tried so far. I have set landscape for the screen orientation and I have also checked the configuration changes in the Activity. There is no configuration changes happening in the Activity. But still the activity is getting re-created. I hope this is because the OS kills my activity. Before the activity is getting killed it reaches onSaveInstanceState(). I am still confused why this is happening in this particular device. I just need to confirm if there is any way to identify the reason for recreating this activity.

Comment: Maybe the device can't keep the activity in memory, use onSaveInstanceState() to save UI data (onPause to save data which you want to keep)

Comment: Is there a specific problem caused by this behavior, or are you just curious as to why your Activity is recreated?